# Limit Laravel 5 pagination links

Tags: php, laravel, pagination, limit

I have pagination with links [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ... 99, 100] and how can I change limit to display [1, 2, 3, ... 98, 99, 100] ? I have custom paginator class, but I can't find this limit to override in my new class.

Comment: I can't find limit, so I can't try something :) Found one question like this on stack, but that answer didn't help me. That code didn't work for me

Comment: It's my custom paginator class: https://gist.github.com/Lotuashvili/e8bc5ca0c1a7b69be81f

Answer (score 2):

By checking the classes I found that you have to override the presenter used by the Paginator.

Its done by calling `render($presenter)` your presenter must extend `BootstrapThreePresenter` If you wish to use bootstrap links and you just have to override the constructor and pass number of links you want on each side  `$this->window = UrlWindow::make($numberOfLinksEachSide)`

These are just instructions you'll have to look by yourself,  I'm sorry for not being able to provide complete code,  I'm on phone. 
Please let me know if this worked.

Comment: I just did the same research and was unsatisfied by inability to configure that (with some flags or instance injections) without extending presenter class.

Comment: Yes it's a shame they didn't do that

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by changing some core fields (although not recommended to change core files).

Find- **vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pagination** and go to **UrlWindow**. On this page find some parameters like- *$onEachSide, $window*. Change and play with these.

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to the same problems... In LengthAwarePaginator updated function links:

```
public function links($view = null, $data = [], $onEachSide = 3)
{
    if(!$data){
        $data = [];
    }
    $this->onEachSide = $onEachSide;
    return $this->render($view, $data);
}
```

And in URLWindow function make:

```
public static function make(PaginatorContract $paginator)
{
    return (new static($paginator))->get($paginator->onEachSide);
}
```

This removes the parameter $onEachSide from function make - which is never passed in anywhere - and allows it to be passed to function links as a parameter.

To use this you need to call this links method like this:

```
{{ $collection->links('view-to-use'|null, $dataArray|null, 2)}}
```

Where 2 is the number on each side.